# How to keep video codec as original one after adding images?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, video-processing

I use ffmpeg to add subtitles to video.
Subtitles are created by imagemagick and I use filter_complex to add these images to video.
And I want to keep original video codec.
Please help me.

Comment: maybe ask on superuser?

Comment: ffmpeg -i 1.mov -i 1.png -loop 1 -framerate 30 -filter_complex "[0:0]scale=1920:trunc(1080/c)*2[c];[1]scale=w=iw*1.0:h=ih[tmp];[c][tmp]overlay=x=(W-w)/2:y=(H*0.95-h):enable='between(t,0.0,1.0)'[c]" -map '[c]' -map 0:a -shortest output.mp4

Comment: The command is something like this

Comment: And I want 1.mov and output.mp4 have the same encoding

Comment: Are you trying to match the codec? Or the codec settings (level, profile, etc)?

Comment: I'm trying to match all

Comment: What is the reason you want to try to match all of the input parameters?